# How char value can be passed to method of int parameter

Tags: java, methods, casting, char, byte

The following code arises compilation error even when the value passed is in the acceptable range.

**Case 1**

```
void test(byte a, int b) { }
```

if the method above is called as `test(2,3);` it gives compile error because the compiler understands that test is a method which accepts two `int` arguments but it has one `byte` and `integer` argument.

But the `byte` value can be `implicitly typecasted` to `int`, so what is the problem here?

```
byte x=2; //valid as value is in between -128 to 127.
```

Same with a case of parameter passing in function call `test(2, 3)`,2 can be assigned to test method argument `byte a`, but why there is a compilation error.

**Case 2**

```
void test(int ch) { }
```

The above code accepts int argument but when char value is passed it compiles successfully. So, strange behavior it is.

Some argue that this implicit casting is applicable when literal values are assigned individually to variables, not to method invocations. (Agrees with the case 1 then what about case 2).

If that the case why the character literal is passed to int argument in the above method(Type casting in the method invocation).

Comment: A char is an unsigned two-byte integer (i.e. going from 0 to 2^16 - 1). It can safely be promoted to an int. As simple as that.

Comment: @JBNizet, byte is 8 bit datatype,why it can't be implicitly type casted to int datatype(32 bit) in method invocation when char 16 bit is implicitly type casted to int in method invocation

Comment: It can. Your first snippet tries to pass a 4-bytes-integer to a method expecting a byte. That's very different from trying to pass a byte to a method expecting a 4-byte integer.

Comment: The implicit typecast works in the declaration, not elsewhere.

Comment: @ShashaankVV The type system and the implicit conversion rules reflect a design decision in the language. The trade-off is between ease of method use and terse notation for cases when implicit conversion would cause no harm vs. compiler complexity and source code readability. Value-contingent type compatibility would require a source code reviewer (who might happen to be the author!) to look up the method declaration to understand. It might also trick the author into thinking of the wrong method signature. The java designers deemed strict static typing the better approach.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot simply pass byte to a method unlike long (`0L`) or float (`0F`). You have to cast to bytes when calling the method. It happens because you pass an integer while it expects a byte.

   ```
   test((byte) 2, (byte) 3);
   ```

   The usual approach is to work with byes in array as `byte[]`.
2. The primitive type `char` is nothing different than and unsigned (greater than zero) integer which can contain values from  0 to 65535. Read more at the Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) about the primitive types.

   > char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

In general, implicit typecasting occurs when the destination type uses a larger memory area than the source type.

Therefore, `char` source(2 bytes) can be implicitly typecasted to `int` destination(4 bytes).

But, `int` source(4 byte) can't be implicitly typecasted to `byte` destination(1 byte).